# Arraylist in a Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to have a `FragmentActivity` where User's input in an `Editext` can store in an array then will show to `Listview` but after entering a value and click the button, the application stopped.

I'm having this kind of output in my `logcat`

```
02-16 21:53:05.950    1315-1315/com.tipmanila.cite.traventurev2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tipmanila.cite.traventurev2, PID: 1315
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.tipmanila.cite.traventurev2.NotesFragment$1.onClick(NotesFragment.java:53)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My `FragmentActivity` look like this

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_fragment, container, false);

    txt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    show = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    save = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getInput = txt.getText().toString();

            if (addArray.contains(getInput)) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Note already added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (getInput == null || getInput.trim().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Input field is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                addArray.add(getInput);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
                show.setAdapter(adapter);
                ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInput)).setText("");

            }


        }
    });


    return v;
```

Comment: Where are you initializing your addArray object?

Comment: Your addArray may be null.

Comment: I'd initialized it on the first part, I did not include it thought it was not that important @KristyWelsh

Comment: `ArrayList<String> addArray = new ArrayList<String>();` this is how my addArray looked like @savepopulation

Comment: Check your layout if there's a listview which has id "listView"

Comment: I do @savepopulation     `<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtInput"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />`